# EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist' when running nestjs in container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nestjs, github-actions

I'm trying to run NestJS app inside a container on VM on Google Cloud via GitHub Actions.

Locally everything is running correctly, however on VM I receive below permission errors:

```
error TS5033: Could not write file '/usr/src/app/dist/users/enums/role.enum.js': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist'.

error TS5033: Could not write file '/usr/src/app/dist/users/enums/role.enum.js.map': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist'.

error TS5033: Could not write file '/usr/src/app/dist/users/users.module.d.ts': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist'.

error TS5033: Could not write file '/usr/src/app/dist/users/users.module.js': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist'.

error TS5033: Could not write file '/usr/src/app/dist/users/users.module.js.map': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist'.

error TS5033: Could not write file '/usr/src/app/dist/users/users.resolver.d.ts': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist'.

error TS5033: Could not write file '/usr/src/app/dist/users/users.resolver.js': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist'.

error TS5033: Could not write file '/usr/src/app/dist/users/users.resolver.js.map': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist'.

error TS5033: Could not write file '/usr/src/app/dist/users/users.service.d.ts': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist'.

error TS5033: Could not write file '/usr/src/app/dist/users/users.service.js': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist'.

error TS5033: Could not write file '/usr/src/app/dist/users/users.service.js.map': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist'.

[6:19:10 PM] Found 154 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

My Dockerfile:

```
###################
# BUILD FOR LOCAL DEVELOPMENT
###################

FROM node:18 As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY --chown=node:node . .

USER node

###################
# BUILD FOR PRODUCTION
###################

FROM node:18 As build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

COPY --chown=node:node --from=development /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules

COPY --chown=node:node . .

RUN npm run build

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN npm ci --only=production && npm cache clean --force

USER node

###################
# PRODUCTION
###################

FROM node:18 As production

COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]
```

docker-compose:

```
services:
  api:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
      target: development
    env_file:
    - .env
    command: npm run start:dev
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5435:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    container_name: pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - '5050:80'
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=${REDIS_PASSWORD}
    command: redis-server --requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
```

CI:

```
name: deployment

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "test" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "test" ]

jobs:

  deploy:

    runs-on: self-hosted

    steps:
    - name: Clone repository 
      uses: actions/checkout@v4
      with:
        ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}
    - run: echo "️ The workflow is now ready to test your code on the runner."
    - name: List files in the repository
      run: |
        ls ${{ github.workspace }}
    - run: cp .env.example .env
    - run: npm install
    - name: deploy
      run: docker compose -f ci.docker-compose.yml up --detach --force-recreate
```

As you can see I'm using only development part from the Dockerfile.

I was using different statements in Dockerfile and docker-compose: chown, mkdir dist, etc., however unsuccessfully.

Edit:
I restructured Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

and docker compose:

```
services:
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app/src

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    container_name: pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - '5050:80'
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=${REDIS_PASSWORD}
    command: redis-server --requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
```

I don't know what was wrong with previous configuration, but works alright with this one.

Answer (score 0):

try this, I hope it works.
check your dist directory's owner, if it was root change it to non-root user `$USER` or delete your directory and rebuild it without sudo permission.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because user "node" does not have the permission to mkdir "dist" and modify files in it.

If I were you, I will connect to the container's file system and check the owner. This is the most reliable way to find the real reason.